# How to fill a MemoryStream with 0xFF bytes?

Tags: c#, padding, memorystream

I have a `MemoryStream` which is created from a File at runtime.

Then the `MemoryStream` is edited and some bytes are removed.

Now I have to maintain a Constant Filesize so I have to fill the `MemoryStream` with 0xFF bytes..

What is the Fastest way to Do this Operation?

I know, that I always can loop through the `MemoryStream` sizes and add 0xFF's but I need to know a faster and more efficient way to do it!

Comment: If you want performance then I would use a byte array instead of a memory stream

Comment: AFAIK, `MemoryStream` = Stream Manipulation of `ByteArray`..So performance is not much hampered

Comment: Do you have to maintain a constant file size in memory? Or does the file size only matters if you write the MemoryStream back to disk?

Comment: @Hans Yes, I have to maintain a constant size in memory...I am not going to write the file after the addition 0xFF as some work remains for it..

Comment: This is a micro-optimization.  It is only interesting to pursue so you'll learn that saving a couple of microseconds is pointless when it costs hundreds of milliseconds just to read the file.  You just can't tell the difference no matter how hard you try.

Comment: First I have to get the Stream filled with 0xFF then `MemoryStream.GetBuffer()`-->Add >100000 of these types of files in a `List<byte[]>`-->Write Them to a new file like chunks...This is all I Want To DO..So Microseconds are important i think![100000 * 2 microsecond = 200 millisecond] [I think it wont be 2 micros but more!!!]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have many bytes to write to the stream, it may be more efficient to write a array rather than each byte individually:

```
static void Fill(this Stream stream, byte value, int count)
{
    var buffer = new byte[64];
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = value;
    }
    while (count > buffer.Length)
    {
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        count -= buffer.Length;
    }
    stream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Comment: In line 10 "`stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);`", why 0 in offset?? The bytes should be added at the end of the stream!

Comment: Please see the documentation of the [Stream.Write Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.write.aspx).

Comment: Oh! Didn't knew that the offset is in the buffer![I never used only Write Method before!]