# How to fill a byte[] with 0xFF bytes?

Tags: c#, arrays, padding

**This question is a follow-up of this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570142/how-to-fill-a-memorystream-with-0xff-bytes)**

I have written a small method to fill a `byte[]` just like the `MemoryStream` :

```
public static Stream FillWithPadding(Stream MS, int Count)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = 0xFF;
    }
    while (Count > buffer.Length)
    {
        MS.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        Count -= buffer.Length;
    }
    MS.Write(buffer, 0, Count);
    return MS;
}

public static byte[] FillWithPadding(byte[] Buffer, int Count)
{
    using (MemoryStream MS = new MemoryStream())
    {
        MS.Write(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
        MemoryStream msw = FillWithPadding(MS, Count) as MemoryStream;
        return msw.GetBuffer();
    }
}
```

This code is not working!!

Instead it is creating `0xFF` + `0x00` at the End!

Can anyone Please clear-up, Why this does not work??

Comment: What is the smallest value of `Count` that produces this "problem?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MemoryStream.GetBuffer()` returns internal byte array that MemoryStream uses to store data. Initially it filled with 0, and filled up to stream length by Write's.

Most likely you want to use MemoryStream.ToArray() instead that returns copy of the buffer truncated to actual length.

Answer (score 0):

That's the position in the Stream Now.
use MS.Position = 0 before Write.

```
public static Stream FillWithPadding(Stream MS, int Count)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = 0xFF;
    }
    MS.Position = 0;
    while (Count > buffer.Length)
    {
        MS.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        Count -= buffer.Length;
    }
    MS.Write(buffer, 0, Count);
    return MS;
}
```

Comment: This is not correct! If you read the other question you will find that i wanted to fill the stream after the contents of itself..[Best way to set position is `MS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)`]